# Optimizer won't stop after end new files found by FSW

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have created a CLI Application that will watch over a directory and optimize any new PDF's that are moved into it. There are no errors as of my last build.

The issue I'm having is when I run it the application will detect a change and optimize the changed files, but it doesn't stop the cycle of optimizing the new files.

How would I set a stopping point in the optimization process once it reaches the end of the new files?

```
public class Methods
        {
            [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
            public static void Optimize()
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                PDFNet.Initialize();

                string input_Path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\testinpactive\";
                string output_Path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\output\";
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(input_Path, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Optimizing {fileName}");
                    string sub = file.Substring(41, 7);
                    CreateFolder(output_Path + sub);

                    // CreateFolder(output_Path + );
                    try
                    {
                        using (PDFDoc doc = new PDFDoc(file))
                        {
                            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            // Example 1) Simple optimization of a pdf with default settings.
                            doc.InitSecurityHandler();
                            Optimizer.Optimize(doc);
                            doc.Save(output_Path + sub + fileName, SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized);
                            // File Delete Process
                            //File.Delete(input_Path + files);
                            //Console.WriteLine("File Deleted");
                            Console.WriteLine("Done..\n");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (PDFNetException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

            public static void Run()
            {
                // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
                // Params: Path, and filter
                using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\testinpactive", "*.pdf"))
                {
                    // To watch SubDirectories 
                    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

                    FswHandler Handler = new FswHandler();

                    // Add event handlers.
                    watcher.Created += Handler.OnCreated;

                    // Begin watching.
                    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                    // Wait for the user to quit the program.
                    Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
                    while (Console.Read() != 'q');
                }
            }
            public class FswHandler
            {
                public void OnCreated(Object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
                {
                    // Write out Path (Testing)
                    Console.WriteLine($"FILE: {e.FullPath} CHANGE-TYPE: {e.ChangeType}");
                    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
                    Optimize();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Right now you are optimizing ALL files when any file is changed.  There should be a filename in the `FileSystemEventArgs `.

Comment: @BenVoigt So would the best solution be to remove the foreach from the Optimize method and just set it to optimize 1 file with the ```FileSystemEventArgs``` filename?

Comment: That's certainly one option.  Another is to rename (to outside the directory) each file when you process it.  A lot depends on how you expect to handle files which appeared while your program wasn't running.

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to @BenVoigt for explaining what I was doing wrong.

Here are the changes I made to my code to fix the issue.

```
public static void Optimize(string filePath, string outputPath, string fileName, string fileNum)
            {
                PDFNet.Initialize();
                try
                {
                        using (PDFDoc doc = new PDFDoc(filePath)) 
                        {
                            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            // Example 1) Simple optimization of a pdf with default settings.
                            doc.InitSecurityHandler();
                            Optimizer.Optimize(doc);
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath + filePath.Substring(41, 7));
                            doc.Save(filePath, SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized);
                            //doc.Save(outputPath + fileNum + fileName, SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized);
                            Console.WriteLine("Done..\n");
                        }
                }
                catch (PDFNetException e)
                {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }

            public static void Run()
            {
                // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
                // Params: Path, and filter
                using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\testinpactive", "*.pdf"))
                {
                    // To watch SubDirectories 
                    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

                    FswHandler Handler = new FswHandler();

                    // Add event handlers.
                    watcher.Created += Handler.OnCreated;

                    // Begin watching.
                    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                    // Wait for the user to quit the program.
                    Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
                    while (Console.Read() != 'q');
                }
            }
            public class FswHandler
            {
                public void OnCreated(Object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
                {
                    string output = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\output";
                    // Write out Path (Testing)
                    Console.WriteLine($"FILE: {e.FullPath} CHANGE-TYPE: {e.ChangeType}");
                    Thread.Sleep(800);
                    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
                    Optimize(e.FullPath, output, e.Name.Substring(7), e.FullPath.Substring(40, 8));
                }

            }
```